# How to install tplink driver without internet?

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, package-management, dpkg

[This Guide](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201805/20180508/Installation%20Guide%20for%20Linux.pdf) is for installing drivers for my WiFi adapter, but I haven't got an `gcc` installed yet and I haven't got an internet access. I tried manualy `dpkg` build-essentials but I have an error:

```
dpkg: error processing package build-essential (--install):  
dependency problems - leaving unconfirmed
```

I think it is problem with this that I won't have `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` done, but I can't perform it cause as I told, I haven't got an internet connection.